# Unity Rotate Sphere To Point Directly Upwards Based On Child Point

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've got a 3d sphere which I've been able to plot a point on using longitude and latitude thanks to some work of another developer I've found online. I think I understand what its doing.

What I need to do now is rotate my planet so the point is always at the top most point (ie the north pole) but I'm not sure how to do this. I'm probably missing some important fundamentals here so I'm hoping the answer can assist in my future learning.

Here's an image showing what I have - The blue line is a line coming from the longitude and latitude I have plotted and I need to rotate the planet so that line is basically pointing directly upwards.

https://ibb.co/2y24FxS

If anyone is able to advise it'd be very much appreciated.

Comment: How familiar are you with using a quaternion to specify the rotation of an object?

Comment: Nah my bad; I misread the question the first time which is why my first comment didn't make a ton of sense.

Comment: No problem but "not very" would be the answer to your question if I'm honest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, Unity uses a coordinate system where the y-axis points up.
If the point on your sphere was in the xy-plane, you'd just have to determine the angle between the radius-vector (starts in the center of the sphere, ends on the point in question) and the y-axis, and than rotate by that amount around the z-axis, so that the radius vector becomes vertical. But your point is at an arbitrary location in 3D space - see the image below. So one way to go about it is to first bring the point to the xy-plane, then continue from there.

[image]

Calculate the radius vector, which is just **r** = **x**-**sphereCenter**. Make a copy of it, set y to zero, so that you have (x, 0, z) - which is just the projection of the vector **r** on the horizontal xz-plane - let's call the copy **rXZ**.

Determine the signed angle between the x-axis and **rXZ** (use `Vector3.SignedAngle(xAxis, rXZ, yAxis)`, see [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.SignedAngle.html)), and create a rotation matrix M1 that rotates the sphere in the *opposite* direction around the vertical (negate the angle). This should place your point in the xy-plane.

Now determine the angle between **r** and the y-axis (`Vector3.SignedAngle(r, yAxis, zAxis)`), and create a new rotation matrix M2 that rotates by that angle around the zAxis. (I think for this second one, the simpler `Vector3.Angle` will work as well.)

So, what you want now is to combine the two matrices (by multiplying them) into a single transform (I'm assuming this is a transformation in the *local coordinate system* of the sphere, where (0, 0, 0) is the sphere's center). If I'm not mistaken, Unity uses column-major matrices, so the multiplication order should be M = M2 * M1 (the rightmost matrix is applied first).

Reorient your globe using M as a local transform, and it should bring your point to the top. You can also create M3 = M1.inverse, and then do M = M3 * M2 * M1, to preserve the original angular offset from the xy-plane.

Check for edge cases, such as **r** already being vertical (pointing straight up, or straight down).

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to accept this answer though to be honest it's quite a bit more complicated than what I was hoping for so it's quite over my head. Appreciate the effort you took to answer however and I hope this answer helps others.

Comment: Wait, one question @Filip.
I don't have a ton of experience with Unity, but doesn't it have a function to find the quaternion (or vector3) representing the difference between the radius vector `r` and the (0, 1, 0) vector? 
Or is that functionality not built-in to Unity afterall?

Comment: @MathewAlden: I don't have a lot of experience with Unity either. Looks like you're right, though: I found [Quaternion.FromToRotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.FromToRotation.html) in the docs, which seems to be perfect for this problem (and you can smoothly interpolate between quaternions, so that's another plus).

Comment: @MartinCrawley - I can't update the answer ATM, but take a look at [Quaternion.FromToRotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.FromToRotation.html) - looks like a better/simpler alternative that does exactly what you want (thanks to Mathew Alden for pointing us in the right direction).

Comment: @Filip lit, glad I could help a bit.